# Bare Metal Programming on STM32WB55 or STM32F10

Tags: arm, stm32, bare-metal

I want To do Bare Metal Programming on STM32 using STM32CubeIDE.

have (STM32WB55 and STM32F103).

what all header files and source files are required to use peripheral registers and make own Device driver. For E.g: in AVR 8 bit MCU for doing bare metal we simply have to add iom328.h or iom2560.h header file that will include all the peripheral registers of the MCU and we can easily make LL.

Same way out what are the Header files required for doing it with STM32

CMSIS: is like Initialize our processor and includes its registers.

So what all header files to be included for programming STM32F103 and STM32WB55

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158918/how-do-you-use-cmsis-without-an-ide/60162970#60162970

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a part number macro on the command line (eg: STM32F103xB) and then you just `#include "stm32f1xx.h"`.

The particular device header (`"stm32f103xb.h"`) and the CMSIS headers are included by that one.

If you want to use the HAL library then you also will need to `#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"`.  This includes `"stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h"` which includes all the HAL units drivers you have enabled in the IDE.

I haven't useed the WB parts, but I'm sure the pattern is similar.